# Excel- Turn MARIA ANDERS to M.ANDERS as well as 99 other names, only if the first name is > 3 letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to output a customer name using vlookup. The names are UPPERCASE but I need to limit them if the first name is longer than 3 characters, I need to just use the first letter of the first name. Here is the problem:

If the First name is longer than three characters you should just use the first character
of the first name and put a dot after that. For example if the customer name is “Steve
Johnson” the system should show “S. JOHNSON” or for “Ana Johnson” the system
should show “ANA JOHNSON”.

I should be able to do this without VB. Maybe an IF statement? Like if the first name is > 3 letters, take the first letter in the string?

Comment: This sounds like a homework or similar assignment question. You will have studied ways to achieve the result. In any case, this is not a free script writing service and not a homework completion site. Edit your question and show your approach. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Find` to locate the space, and `If` test the position.  Then either return the string as is, or manipulate the string to suit your needs.  Wrap the whole thing in `Upper` to get upper case

```
=UPPER(IF(FIND(" ",A1)<=4,A1,LEFT(A1,1)&"."&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),999)))
```

Comment: The question reads very much like a test or homework assignment to me.

Comment: @trawbitch vandalising the answer is not acceptable.  If teylen is right and this is homework and you use my answer, be sure to comply with both SO T&C's (attribution required) and your institutions accademic policy